# What is the best solution of fb send intent problems?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, send

We are familiar about FB send intent problem (in official fb app EXTRA TEXT field is not working properly).  It is more than two years this problem has not good solution. I searched many website and found some trick like facebook api, customize code.

At first I tried this. this is working on twiter, google+,fb massanger etc but not in facebook app.

```
String temp = "text to share for testing";
//temp = tv1.getText().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, temp);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share"));
```

Facebook api

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

I don’t understand this. So I don’t want to use it.

Sample customize code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Content to share");
PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
    if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {
        final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
        final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
        shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        shareIntent.setComponent(name);
        v.getContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
        break;
   }
}
```

This customize code is not working for me. It says v can’t resolve a type. I tried to give a type like String, object but unfortunately not working.

Now my question is, Is there any other way or What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: So you need to share content from your app to Facebook ?
Have you tried `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "your app content"); // check if facebook package exists ... Intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);`

Comment: At first I tried this. this is working on twiter, google+,fb massanger etc but not in facebook app. 

String temp = "text to share for testing";
//temp = tv1.getText().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, temp);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share"));

I don't understand your code.  @younes0

Comment: full code: http://pastebin.com/xiYMKDw0

Comment: this code also not working. @younes0